# Does guava have a Map implementation that takes custom hash/equals functions?

Tags: java, guava

Anyone know if Guava has an equivalent version to Functionaljava's [HashMap](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/HashMap.html)?

Comment: I requested [Sets / Maps based on equivalences](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=576), but they were rejected

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, no.

But you can wrap all your keys in [`Equivalence.Wrapper`](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.Wrapper.html) instances using the [`Equivalence`](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) strategy you need:

```
Equivalence<K> equiv = ...
Map<Equivalence.Wrapper<K>, V> map = ...

map.put(equiv.wrap(key), value);
```

Of course this means you need an additional object for every entry in your map. Thus I think a map implementation like you suggest would be nice to have.

Answer (score 7):

I am aware that youre not asking for this specifically, so here goes:
If all you want is a `Map` with a custom equivalence function you may be able to achieve the same by using the standard `TreeMap` that takes a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually what I was looking for, but since it's not actually the answer to the question I decided to accept the other one.

Comment: Just don't expect everything to work correctly if you do this, as explained in the TreeMap javadocs.

Comment: Nice catch. It should still work as expected though. The "only problem" is that the expected behavior is in violation of the `Map` contract. I wonder if its an oversight or on purpose it is so specific about using `equals()`.

Comment: Note that this requires some kind of (sensible) order you can use on your keys